# update and retrieve the updated document mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to update a document with nested subdocuments, but i always retrieve the previus document.

i tried

> { returnOriginal: false }

but it is not working...

this is my code in nodejs

```
almacenCtrl.updateAlmacen = async (req, res) => {
    almacen = await almacenModel.findOneAndUpdate(req.params.id, { $set: req.body }, { returnOriginal: false }, function (err, updated) {
        res.json(updated)
    })
}
```

what am i doing wrong?

//After update i check with mongoshell and the update was updated successfully

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use   `{new : true}` as given below:

```
almacenCtrl.updateAlmacen = async (req, res) => {
    almacen = await almacenModel.findOneAndUpdate(req.params.id, { $set: req.body }, { new: true }, function (err, updated) {
        res.json(updated)
    })
}
```